Applying for Schengen visa sponsored by US permanent resident brother
We are planning a vacation in Denmark, Germany and Switzerland, with Germany being the country for maximum stay. I will be applying visa from a consulate in India, and my brother is the primary sponsor of our trip.
I am employed and the trip time is about seven days.
For applying as a dependent, what are the documents I need to apply for a Schengen visa from the German consulate?
What maximizes the chances of visa approval?
I have recently visited Singapore on a 5 day holiday trip.

What do you mean by ‘applying as dependent’? This question is similar to: Schengen visa application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


We are planning a vacation in Denmark, Germany and Switzerland, with Germany being the country for maximum stay. I will be applying visa from a consulate in India, and my brother is the primary sponsor of our trip. I am employed and the trip time is about seven days.
For applying as a dependent, what are the documents I need to apply for a Schengen visa from the German consulate? What maximizes the chances of visa approval?

Sponsorship only comes up in the Schengen Visa code in relation to visits to Schengen area residents, private accommodation, and sponsorship by (European) organizations. Outside of this specific context, EU and national law in European countries also extends various rights to families but this usually means one's spouse and under-18 children. This does not typically cover adult children, siblings, the parents of an adult, uncles, aunts, etc.
All that to say that since your brother does not live in the EU, he cannot “sponsor” you. You are also highly unlikely to be considered a “dependent” of your brother if you don't live together or rely on him for your day-to-day life. Even if your brother ends up paying for your flight and hotel, your financial and personal situation will be evaluated on its own and it's important to show that you can afford a trip to Germany. Otherwise, it might difficult to obtain a visa.
You can therefore follow the advice in Schengen visa application: what are some helpful tips for preparing? as if you were travelling alone, simply explaining that you would be travelling with your brother where that's relevant.
